# Load the game as it was when the form was loaded

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to put an option in a code when user is finished with the game, the "Play Again" button appears  and when clicked the game can start all over for a user to play. Below is what my code looks like right now, I want to be able to add the Try Again button so when user is done with the game user can start playing the game again.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 244
        If txtbWords.Text = strArr(i) Then
            score = score + txtbWords.Text.Length
            strArr(i) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    txtScore.Text = "Score: " & score

End Sub

Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    txtA.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
    txtC.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
    txtE.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
    btnSubmit.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
    txtbWords.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub



Private i As Integer = 0
Private j As Integer = 3

Public Sub Each_Tick(ByVal o As Object, ByVal sender As EventArgs)
    i = i + 1
    If i = 60 Then
        myDispatcherTimer.Stop() 'Game ends here.
        btnSubmit.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed
    End If
    myTextBlock.Text = i

End Sub


Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    txtA.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    txtC.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    txtE.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    txtK.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    btnSubmit.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    txtbWords.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
    btnStart.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed


    myDispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000)
    ' 100 Milliseconds 
    AddHandler myDispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf Me.Each_Tick
    myDispatcherTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: It’s difficult to say what the best way is without seeing some of your code.

Comment: The answer is usually pretty simple. :-) What you did to start the game when it first loads? Just do the same thing again when the user wants to play again. (You should move all of the game startup code into a method. Call that method when your game is first loaded, and call it whenever you need to start a new game.)